# web scraper for shops with angular / ionic / firestore

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, web-scraping, google-cloud-firestore

i try to build a web scraper for online shops like amazon, ebay with ionic/angular and firestore (cloud functions could be possible).
I want to get some data of the product like: name, description, image, maybe price.
It should return the data as json and not as a live preview.

CORS anywhere looks good but i don't know how to implement it into a firestore cloud function.

Is there a way to implement the Open Graph Protocol into Firestore Cloud Functions or an Angular/Ionic App?

Comment: Sounds too broad and non-concrete for a question here. You can ask on other forums.

Comment: @user202729 The problem and the toolset to solve it have been defined. The OP asks whether it's possible to solve the problem with the toolset or no and what's the starting point. I bet if he added some piece of boilerplate code you wouldn't say it's too broad.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the libraries you want to use and [import](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/handle-dependencies) them. Also notice that Cloud Functions or Firebase Cloud Functions are not meant for running during long time periods, they [will timeout after 1 minute](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#timeout) although it can be extended up to 9 minutes.

But if you are not planning to run a Firebase App I would recommend you to use just a Cloud Function.